# Show JSON response instead of downloading it

Tags: json, rest, http, firefox, itunes

When I go to this URL in Firefox Developer `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=mozart`, it asks me if I want to download a file called `1.txt` containing the results in JSON, but I want to see them directly on my browser.

That may be because the Itunes API doesn't have the `content-type: application/json` header in its responses (the header is `content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8`), but I cannot find another simple API that doesn't require authentication to teach someone how REST APIs work (Twitter, Facebook, Google Maps all require a token). I don't want to use Postman or something like that, it would only confuse this person.

So I seek help here, either to see the Itunes responses directly on my browser, or to find another API where there isn't this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are actually a lot of APIs that don't require authentication, for example there is a list at https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type `about:config` on your address bar
2. Search for 'devtools.jsonview.enabled'
3. If the status is not **default**, right click on the line and select 'Toggle'

After that the json should start appearing on the page